# How to prevent unwanted access to Fact table?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, row-level-security

I am using RLS in SSAS and it works fine:

[image]

I filter the table **Project**... Therefore, if a certain group has access only to Project X. They only see that.

(I use visuals in POWER BI that use a mix of fact measures with the **Project** dimension).

No issues there, the RLS works fine.

My question is: if the **Project** dimension is not pulled/used; the access does not get enforced... (I have control over POWER BI, and I pull/use the **Project** dimensions in all my visuals...  But any user can connect to the model (through excel for example) and see ALL the data in the fact. How can I avoid this?

(I am not too worried, since in the fact I have mostly keys data, but they can still see 'revenue' for example...)

Answer (score 0):

> But any user can connect to the model (through excel for example) and see ALL the data in the fact. How can I avoid this?

If there's a filter path from Project to Fact, and you have RLS rules on Project Fact will be filtered for all users in the RLS role, regardless of whether they query Project directly.

Comment: Are you describing Excel behavior?

Because Power BI does not behave like that… 

I have a cube that is used in both a   Overview.pbix  and a   OnlyPersonal.pbix   and the same user accessing the same cube can see different things on each .pbix (The trick is done by another ‘mask’ table…      The user is in 2 roles: in one role, it has FALSE() for the ‘mask’ table and in the other role, it can see its own data…  In Overview.pbix the ‘mask’ table is not on any of the visuals or filters, therefore the RLS doesn’t get enforced in the Overview.pbix).

Comment: If a user is in multiple roles they _should_ see all the rows available to either role.

Comment: In Power BI it depends on what you “pull” in the Report pane. If I pull the “mask” table in any filter, the more restrictive access gets enforced… If the “Mask” table is not used, the RLS does not get enforced.

That is how I can create using the same cube, a .pbix showing all rows and .pbix only displaying personal rows. And the same user accessing the same cube (different report) sees different rows.

Comment: Is the "cube" a power BI dataset, or an SSAS Tabular model, or SSAS Multi-Dimensional model?

Comment: Sorry, yes, by a "cube" I mean "SSAS tabular model"

Comment: Can you add more details about the data model and behavior you are seeing?  What you are describing is unexpected.